# How do I display a hidden data element when searched

Tags: html, css, seo

Using meta tags but the div element containing the content is hidden. How can it be displayed in search results

Still trying to figure out the best solution to approach a single page website without creating many separate pages

Comment: See [Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling? - Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140250/do-search-engines-perform-js-rendering-while-crawling), specifically the section in my answer titled "Assign each piece of content its own URL" which says how to do that in a single page framework.